# Using Custom Queryset as manager, filter again after a custom filtered method

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a custom QuerySet:

```
class EntityModelQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(is_active=True)
```

In the model, I sent the QuerySet to work as manager:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
 is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 objects = EntityModelQuerySet.as_manager()
```

In View I try:

```
Entity.objects.active.filter(is_home=True)
```

It gives me an error:

```
'function' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Why, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `active` function to return queryset, just add `()`:

```
Entity.objects.active().filter(is_home=True)
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't noticed that I don't call the method, I thought something else is wrong